# String List from a Textbox Lines

Tags: vb.net

how do i get this from the textbox?

```
oOldList = New List(Of String) From {"1,2", "3,5", "7,9", "12,15", "21,24", "31,36", "41,49", "51,54"}
```

Code:

```
Public Sub RandomizeList()
  Dim oControl As List(Of Integer)
  Dim oOldList As List(Of String)
  Dim oNewList As List(Of String)
  Dim iRandom As Integer
  Dim oRandom As Random

  oControl = New List(Of Integer)
  oOldList = New List(Of String) From {"1,2", "3,5", "7,9", "12,15", "21,24", "31,36", "41,49", "51,54"}
  oNewList = New List(Of String)
  oRandom = New Random

  oOldList.ForEach(Sub(Item)
                     Do
                       iRandom = oRandom.Next(oOldList.Count)

                       If Not oControl.Contains(iRandom) Then
                         oControl.Add(iRandom)
                         Exit Do
                       End If
                     Loop

                     oNewList.Add(oOldList(iRandom))
                   End Sub)

  Debug.WriteLine("")
  Debug.WriteLine("Old List")
  Debug.WriteLine("----------")
  oOldList.ForEach(Sub(Item) Debug.WriteLine(Item))

  Debug.WriteLine("")
  Debug.WriteLine("New List")
  Debug.WriteLine("----------")
  oNewList.ForEach(Sub(Item) Debug.WriteLine(Item))
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to make work?

Comment: Dim Numbers() As Integer = TextBox1.Text.Split(vbCrLf).Select(Function(v) CInt(v)).ToArray()
oOldList = New List(Of String) From {Numbers.ToString}

Comment: I was looking for a question, which you didn't ask.

Comment: Start by debugging and keeping it simple.  Pull out just the Text, and look at it in the debugger.  Then do a split and loop through each line to see what you get.  I guarantee you will figure it out yourself, and then you can try and simplify it down to one LINQ query line.

Comment: Make the Textbox a Richtextbox.  It has lines() already.

Comment: TextBox has `Lines` as well

Comment: how do i do this? if the above code doesn't work at all. Dim Numbers () As Integer = RichTextBox1.Text.Split (vbCrLf) .ToArray ()
         oNewList = New List (Of String) From {Numbers.ToString}

Comment: in a line, there are 2 values (gen 24,26) so it is not integer. oOldList = New List(Of String) From {"1,2", "3,5", "7,9", "12,15", "21,24", "31,36", "41,49", "51,54"} I should put these values in a textbox and know how to take them automatically.

Comment: Why are you making an array of integers and then changing that array into a list of String? You can simply call `ToList` instead of `ToArray` and there seems to be no need to convert to int. Additionally, there is no need to call split on new line, simply use `Lines` as suggested

Comment: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] -         Numbers = TextBox1.Text.Split(vbCrLf).Select(Function(v) CInt(v)).ToList()
        oNewList = New List(Of String)
        oNewList.Add(Numbers.ToString)

Comment: Can you clarify you question by editing you the original post.

Comment: @Anu6is - yes it does.  My bad.

Comment: I put all the code. now i hope it will be ok. still nothing works.

Comment: It can be done with oOldList.Add (anything), but I don't know how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I am still unclear as to what exactly you are trying to achieve, however I assume this is the direction you are aiming at.

```vb
Dim oOldList As List(Of String) = TextBox1.Lines.ToList
```

- Using `Lines` removes the need to do `Split(vbCrLf)`
- By default, `Lines` returns an array, so call `ToList` to convert that to a list
- I'm not certain why you are using `Select` to convert the Strings to Int (so I omitted doing that at all.